How to build an nginx conf to accommodate wildcards in location?
I have a server and 2 locations. The proxy_pass is the same for both but I need to pass a different header
server {

   location ~ /deployments/*xx*/ {
      proxy_pass $uri;
      proxy_set_header custom-header val1
   }

   location ~ /deployments/*yy*/ {
      proxy_pass $uri;
      proxy_set_header custom-header val2
   }

}

Is this the right way to use regex to accommodate the wildcard uri? What would be the best way to implement this?

why not use two different request path? it is not very clear what you are doing. moreover what have you been attempting to solve this problem and research?

The reason I can't use different request paths is because I am not sure how many paths there might be. But all the paths containing 'xx' need header to val1 and paths containing 'yy' need header to val2

I have tried location ~ /deployments/*xx*/ { ... } and location ~ /deployments/.*xx.*/ { ... }. Neither seem to work

you need only /deploy1 and /deploy2 imho

I figured it out, this is the right format
server {

   location ~ ^(/deployments/).*(xx).* {
      proxy_pass $uri;
      proxy_set_header custom-header val1
   }

   location ~ ^(/deployments/).*(yy).* {
      proxy_pass $uri;
      proxy_set_header custom-header val2
   }

}

